# Oracle Apex PL/SQL - store value from text field into variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

In an Oracle APEX page, I have some text fields in a region. The text I put in should be saved in a table.  I have a select list on the page that lets me determine whether I should use the value from text field A or from text field B.  My select list displays the static values Yes and No.

If my select list value is 'Yes', I take value B (new input from the text field and if it is 'No', value A = value B).

Here what I've tried:

```
declare Value_C varchar2(20) := null;

begin
  if :P1_YN = 'No'
    then :Value_C := P1_Value_A;
  else :Value_C := P1_Value_B
  end if;

  insert into [table_name]
  (ID, PATH, ValueA, ValueB)
  values
  (:P1_ID, :P1_PATH, :P1_Value_A, :Value_C);
end;
```

When I run this code, however, I get an error

> Err-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "Value_C" in application
>   "xxx".

Comment: I believe I have focused your question without changing your meaning.  If I failed to understand what you were asking, however, please let me know.

Comment: Oh thank you a lot Justin. That's excactly how I want to express myself.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to declare a local variable `value_c`, you wouldn't prefix it with a colon.  You would put a colon before `P1_Value_A` and `P1_Value_B` when you do the assignment assuming that those are also items on your page.  Your code is also missing a semicolon after the assignment in the `else` block.

```
declare 
  Value_C varchar2(20) := null;
begin
  if :P1_YN = 'No'
  then 
    Value_C := :P1_Value_A;
  else 
    Value_C := :P1_Value_B;
  end if;

  insert into [table_name]
  (ID, PATH, ValueA, ValueB)
  values
  (:P1_ID, :P1_PATH, :P1_Value_A, Value_C);
end;
```

would be syntactically correct assuming that all the identifiers that have the colon prefix are items on your page.

Comment: Hi Justin, your explanation was really useful. Thank you again :)